# Loewy Length of Tjurina algebra

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Suppose $k$ is an algebraically closed field with characteristic $0$. Let $k[x_0,\ldots,x_n]$ be the graded polynomial ring and $f\in k[x_0,\ldots,x_n]$ be a homogeneous polynomial of degree $d$ and $A=k[x_0,\ldots,x_n]/(f)$. Let $J=(\partial f/\partial x_0,\ldots,\partial f/\partial x_n) $ be the Jacobian ideal of $A$.

Assume $A$ has an isolated singularity. It turns out that the Tjurina algebra $A/J$ is Artinian. In the paper [Orlov spectra: bounds and gaps](https://arxiv.org/abs/1012.0864), the authors mentioned in the proof of Lemma 5.18 that
the Loewy length of $A/J$ is $d(n+1)-2n-1$ by Macaulay's theorem, where the Loewy length of $A/J$ is the minimal number $m$ such that $((x_1,\ldots,x_n)/(f,J))^m=0$.

> My question: what is Macaulay's theorem here? It doesn't have a reference in their paper.

I can't find this theorem in Google. I also don't know how to show the Loewy length is that number. Is Macaulay's theorem well-known?

Comment: @user4567 STOP suggesting edits that you make where you do nothing but strip salutations.

Comment: When I searched I rapidly found [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.09168.pdf) says something similar, citing [this other paper](https://www.math.unl.edu/~bharbourne1/ReginaWorkshop/ReginaAccessOnly/MacAulay1927.pdf) which as the original source.  Does that second one look right?

Comment: @rschwieb Thank you. The second paper looks similar. I will take a further read.

Comment: Macaulay's theorem describes exactly what the Hilbert functions of a standard graded algebra over a field can look like. Bruns and Herzog's Cohen-Macaulay rings devotes an entire section to it (Section 4.2). Note that the Hilbert series of an Artinian standard graded algebra is a polynomial and its degree is the Loewy length.

Comment: @metalspringpro Sounds great. Thank you so much. This helps a lot.